# How can I recognize the following group of strings using a grammar or regex?

Tags: regex, grammar, combinatorics

The only thing I've noticed is that the number of elements for each n is the [Catalan Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

We only have even n's. 
This list goes on indefinetely.

```
n=2
ab

n=4
aabb
abab

n=6
aaabbb
aababb
aabbab
abaabb
ababab

n=8
aaaabbbb
aaababbb
aaabbabb
aaabbbab
aabaabbb
aabababb
aababbab
aabbaabb
aabbabab
abaaabbb
abaababb
abaabbab
ababaabb
abababab
```

This list can be generated by the following python code: http://pastebin.com/hynjWTrp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no regular expressions, since the language us not regular.

The generic form for matching a and b is the same as for matching parentheses, and it's a Conext-Free Grammar:

```
S -> e | AS
A -> e | aAb
```

Where `e` is the empty string.

Comment: I'm having problems testing it, can you point me a parser type for this grammar? I'm using nltk http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch08.html